# Big list of books on counterexamples and other clever observations in different topics

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

This question is related to [Counterexample Math Books](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279347/counterexample-math-books), but I'm looking for books in areas which aren't covered there (for example, number theory).

In addition, books that focus on clever *observations* that comment on theorems, proofs, examples and counterexamples are also very welcome.

Comment: One could argue that theorems and proofs *are* clever observations...

Comment: @lhf you're right. I edited the question.

Comment: I would nominate [Unsolved Problems in Group Theory. The Kourovka Notebook](http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.0300) to be called "Counterexamples in Group Theory". It is a collection of open problems in Group Theory, and each edition (now at 18th) contains new problems and numerous comments on problems from previous editions - some of them solved positively, some with counterexamples discovered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three additional recommendations for your *extensive book list* (considering your related questions :-))

> **Number Theory**
>
> Books dedicated to counterexamples in number theory are not known to me, but since you pointed to number theory here are books with related information
>
> - [Unsolved Problems in Number Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441919287) by *Richard K. Guy*.
>
> This book is *not dedicated for a beginner in mathematics*. Although many of the questions are formulated using basic number theoretical terminology, most of them are really tough problems (namely at least partly unsolved). But it provides a good impression which problems are subject to research and valuable for the interested reader: For each problem there is an *extensive list of references*. Hundreds of problems are listed organized into six categories: *prime numbers*, *divisibility*, *additive number theory*, *Diophantine equations*, *sequences of integers*, and miscellaneous.
>
> - [Problems in Algebraic Number Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387221824) by *Jody Esmonde* and *M. Ram Murty*.
>
> This *is a fine book* appropriate for self-study after you have mastered a course in undergraduate algebra. It provides 500 problems and presents thereby concepts and ideas from *algebraic number theory*. It consists of two parts. The first presents theorems and problems (exercises), the second part provides complete solutions.
>
> **Comments on theorems, proofs, etc.**
>
> - [A Problem Seminar](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387907653) by *Donald J.Newman*.
>
> This is a helpful booklet in training for the advanced undergraduate. The problems are organised in *Estimation Theory*, *Generating Functions*, *Limits of Integrals*, *Expectations*, *Prime Factors*, *Category Arguments* and *Convexity*. My impression is the book is in degree of difficulty and in its spirit similar to the book *Counterexamples in Calculus*. I appreciate both of them.
>
> *A word of warning*: Please keep in mind that the *Counterexamples books* **differ significantly in their degree of difficulty** from less demanding (*Counterexamples in Calculus*) to highly sophisticated (e.g. *Counterexamples in Topological Vector Spaces*). While the first is accessible (and a good training!) after you have mastered a course in undergraduate analysis, the latter demands a profound knowledge in point-set topology and functional analysis.
>
> - [Problem-Solving Through Problems](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387961712) by *Loren C.Larson*
>
> This is a helpful guide explaining **how to solve problems**. E.g. chapter 1 *Heuristics* provides helpful hints like *Searching for a Pattern*, *Drawing a Figure*, *Formulate an Equivalent Problem*, *Modify the Problem*, *Choose Effective Notation*, *Exploit Symmetry*, *Divide into Cases*, *Work Backward*, *Argue by Contradiction*, *Pursue Parity*, *Consider Extreme Cases* and *Generalize*. This book is accessible for the undergraduate student and it can be considered as good training on the job and prerequisite. Namely a prerequisite before looking at the more demandig problems from [Problem-Solving Strategies](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387982191) which is an answer according to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/954522) from you.
>
> **Clever observations that comment on examples**
>
> - [Irresistible Integrals](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521796369) by *George Boros* and *Victor H. Moll*.
>
> This is a great collection of beautiful integrals and techniques on how to solve them. It provides a nice survey of standard techniques which you may know after you have mastered an undergraduate course in one-variable calculus. One important fact is that knowledge in real calculus is sufficient. The techniques presented here *do not require* any knowledge in *complex analysis*.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your suggestions are always precious. I particularly appreciated Donald Newman's *A Problem Seminar*.

Comment: I see, you already know a lot of good books, but wait! At the time I'm answering your last question about fun books! :-)

Comment: @Dal: Thanks for the bounty and also for pointing to interesting refs in your questions. This is also a good source for me to get information about great books! :-)

Answer (score 5):

A great book about proofs is Martin Aigner, Günter Ziegler: *Proofs from THE BOOK.*

Comment: This is not quite what I was asking for with this particular question. Still, it is a GREAT book. So +1 and many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Gary L. Wise, Eric B. Hall - Counterexamples in Probability and Real Analysis, is a very good book related to what you are looking for.

Comment: That one is mentioned at the referenced question...

Comment: @learning maths : You should avoid using english chat shortcuts such as "u can try" on this website.